# Can deportation be reversed?

Tags: united-states, immigration

Suppose, for example, that a US permanent resident is convicted of an aggravated felony. They will probably go to prison and then be deported once they are released from prison under INA 237(a)(2)(A)(iii). They will also be banned from the US for 20 years after removal under INA 212(a)(9)(A)(ii).

Now suppose that years later, it comes to light that the person was actually innocent and the prosecutors had fabricated evidence, or for some similar reason the person is able to get their conviction overturned. Presumably, this person would no longer be treated as an aggravated felon for immigration purposes (so the 20 year bar would be reversed) and since that would mean that there was no valid basis for removal in the first place, they would also no longer be considered to have "been ordered removed" for the purposes of INA 212(a)(9)(A)(ii) (so the 10 year bar would not be applicable either).

This is not really reversing the deportation though, because the person doesn't live in the US anymore, perhaps no longer has ties to the US, and doesn't have a way to come back to the US: they no longer have an immigrant visa or a green card. They might no longer be eligible to re-immigrate in their original immigrant category (for example, a diversity visa). Could they petition a court to find that

1. the order of removal is void, and thus the termination of their LPR status by the order of removal is also void, and
2. they should be granted (as equitable relief) the right to return to the US within a reasonable period of time and be treated as a returning resident under INA 101(a)(27)(A) despite the fact that they have lived outside the US for years without ties to the US and without the intention of returning;

and would a court be able to grant such relief?

Comment: "This is not really reversing the deportation though" this is the short answer to the title question. but, your later elaboration still presents an important and valid legal question.

Comment: @ohwilleke Obviously there are aspects of deportation that cannot be reversed: for example, the person will not get the money they would have earned if they had been able to work in the US. The title is just a title; it's not the question.

Comment: I think it is possible to re-open a removal case, but I am not familiar with the details.